okhttp ResponseBody closed IOException when parsing
Why im getting closed IOException when trying to parse to JSONArray
 Response resp = call.execute();
    
                    try (ResponseBody body = resp.body()) {
                        jsonArray = JSONArray.parse(body.byteStream());
                        // jsonArray = JSONArray.parse(body);
                    }


The exception is: closed","exception":"java.io.IOException:
closed\n\tat
okio.RealBufferedSource$inputStream$1.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:157)\n\tat
java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)\n\tat
java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)\n\tat
java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)\n\tat
java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)\n\tat
com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray.parse(JSONArray.java:150)\n\tat
com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray.parse(JSONArray.java:129)

